# Cmake: accessing qtvirtual keyboard module

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, qtvirtualkeyboard, cmake-modules

Can anyone do a simple example of including qtvirtualkeyboard module into a cmake file? I want to access the classes but I cannot figure out how to include it.

Answer (score 3):

Qt's virtual keyboard is just another module, it can be loaded with [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_package.html). The minimal example of cmake file being:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0 FATAL_ERROR)

PROJECT("MyKeyboard")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QTDIR})

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets VirtualKeyboard REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

add_executable("MyKeyboard"
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries("MyKeyboard" Qt5::Widgets Qt5::VirtualKeyboard)
```

Answer (score 1):

This example should work. It was compiled using CMake 3.1.1 and Qt 5.11.1

[The code](https://github.com/ftena/qml-c/tree/master/virtualkeyboard-cmake-56202469) is available in my GitHub account. The QML example is based on the [example provided by Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html).

**Main CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

# 3rd party tools
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Qml Quick REQUIRED)

# Directory with the source code
add_subdirectory(src)
```

**CMakeLists.txt included in the subdirectory**

```
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${QtQml_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS} ${QtQml_DEFINITIONS} ${${Qt5Quick_DEFINITIONS}})

qt5_add_resources(QT_RESOURCES qml.qrc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(PROJECT "virtualkeyboard-cmake-56202469")

project(${PROJECT})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -fstrict-aliasing -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-variable")

if(NOT DEFINED HEADERS)
    file(GLOB HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED SOURCES)
    file(GLOB SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
endif()

source_group("Header Files" FILES ${HEADERS})
source_group("Source Files" FILES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${PROJECT} ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT}
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::Quick
    )
```

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view(QString("qrc:/main.qml"));

    if (view.status() == QQuickView::Error)
        return -1;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1

Rectangle {
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    color: "#F6F6F6"

    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: content.width
        contentHeight: content.height
        interactive: contentHeight > height
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick

        property real scrollMarginVertical: 20

        MouseArea  {
            id: content
            width: flickable.width
            height: textEditors.height + 24

            onClicked: focus = true

            Column {
                id: textEditors
                spacing: 15
                x: 12
                y: 12
                width: parent.width - 26

                Label {
                    color: "#565758"
                    text: "Tap fields to enter text"
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    font.pixelSize: 22
                }
                TextField {
                    width: parent.width
                    placeholderText: "One line field"
                    onAccepted: passwordField.focus = true
                }
                TextField {
                    id: passwordField
                    width: parent.width
                    echoMode: TextInput.Password
                    placeholderText: "Password field"
                    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoAutoUppercase | Qt.ImhPreferLowercase | Qt.ImhSensitiveData | Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText
                    onAccepted: upperCaseField.focus = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```